# Getting empty data from state | Using useState React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've stumbled upon an issue with the useState scope. I'm trying to create a dynamic Bootstrap Form where the user will be able to add more rows to the group (those rows will containt energy-related data). When I enter something to those fields, enterEnvironmentData function fires empty data. Can anyone explain that to me, please? Where is my mistake?

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

const [ defaultData, ] = useState(
    {
        envName: undefined,
        heatingCosts: 0,
        waterCosts: 0,
        gasCosts: 0,
        environmentCosts: 0,
        frazzle: 0
    }
);
const [ groupsData, setGroupsData ] = useState( {
    group0: {
        id: 0,
        rowsAmount: 0,
        rows: []
    }
} );

// *enterEnvironmentData* function fires when input fields are changed

const enterEnvironmentData = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const group = event.target.getAttribute('data-group'),
        row = event.target.getAttribute('data-row');
    
    console.log("groupsData - ", groupsData);
    console.log("data-group - ", group);
    console.log("data-row - ", row);
    console.log("groupsData[", group, "]", groupsData[group]);
    console.log("groupsData[", group, "].rows", groupsData[group].rows); // rows array is empty ???
};

let [ environment, setEnvironment] = useState( {
    group0: [],
    group1: []
} );

// *toggleChangeRowsAmount* fires when changing Form.Control's value (elements amount)

const toggleChangeRowsAmount = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
    let value = +event.target.value,
        name = event.target.name;

    if ( value <= 0 ) {
        value = 0;
    } else {
        setGroupsData({
            ...groupsData,
            [name]: { ...groupsData[name], rowsAmount: value }
        })
    }
};

// *addRows* fires when clicking on "Add" button

const addRows = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.getAttribute('name'),
        rows = groupsData[name].rowsAmount,
        length = groupsData[name].rows.length;
    let arr = [],
        rowNames = [];
    
    for (let i = length; i < rows+length; i++) {
        let newRow = `row${i}`;
        rowNames.push(newRow);
        arr.push(
            {
                [newRow]: defaultData
            }
        );
    }

    setGroupsData({
        ...groupsData,
        [name]: {
            ...groupsData[name],
            rows: [
                ...groupsData[name].rows,
                ...arr
            ]
        }
    });

    let items = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        let rn = rowNames[i];
        items.push(
            <Form.Row key={ rowNames[i] }>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Environment
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        data-group={ name }
                        data-row={ rn }
                        value={ arr[i][rn].envName }
                        onChange={ enterEnvironmentData }
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Heating Costs
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        data-group={ name }
                        data-row={ rn }
                        value={ arr[i][rn].heatingCosts }
                        onChange={ enterEnvironmentData }
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Water Costs
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        data-group={ name }
                        data-row={ rn }
                        value={ arr[i][rn].waterCosts }
                        onChange={ enterEnvironmentData }
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Gas Costs
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        data-group={ name }
                        data-row={ rn }
                        value={ arr[i][rn].gasCosts }
                        onChange={ enterEnvironmentData }
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Environment Costs
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        data-group={ name }
                        data-row={ rn }
                        value={ arr[i][rn].environmentCosts }
                        onChange={ enterEnvironmentData }
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Frazzle
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        data-group={ name }
                        data-row={ rn }
                        value={ arr[i][rn].frazzle }
                        onChange={ enterEnvironmentData }
                    />
                </Col>
            </Form.Row>
        );
    };

    setEnvironment({
        ...environment,
        [name]: [
            ...environment[name],
            ...items
        ]
    });
};

useEffect(
    () => {
        console.log("groupsData - ", groupsData, ", environment - ", environment);
    },
    [ groupsData, environment ]
)
    
return (
    <div className="EntryForm">
        <div className="container">
            <Form>
                <div key="group0" >
                    <h4>
                        Group
                    </h4>
                    <Form.Label>
                        Elements Amount                      
                        <Form.Control
                            type="number"
                            name="group0"
                            value={ groupsData["group0"].rowsAmount }
                            onChange={ toggleChangeRowsAmount }
                        />
                        <Button
                            variant="info"
                            name="group0"
                            onClick={ addRows }
                        >
                            Add
                        </Button>
                    </Form.Label>
                    {
                        environment["group0"].map( env => env)
                    }
                </div>
            </Form>
        </div>            
    </div>
)
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

P.S. Nothing is sumbited at this Form (yet).

Comment: try <Form.Control
                            type="text"
                            data-group={ name }
                            data-row={ rn }
                            value={ arr[i][rn].envName }
                            onChange={(e)=>{enterEnvironmentData(e)} }
                        />

Comment: That's a lot code for one question. You'll probably get better responses if you can reduce  it to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yoshi I'm not sure how to import Bootstrap here, sorry

Comment: I actually meant for you to reduce the code, might even remove the bootstrap dependency.

Comment: @Yoshi Unfortunately, I tried and no one understood the problem

Comment: @NaveenKashyap it doesn't help

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Seeing your code, I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. If you could explain from a "what should happen" perspective?

Comment: @Yoshi There's a dynamic form where I add rows with input fields. I wanna make those fileds change state data (objects inside groupsData.group0.rows array) but somehow state data (groupsData.group0.rows array) appears to be empty

Comment: @Yoshi That's my post but I don't understand how to fix that

Comment: I understand that it's your updated post, usually you should rather update this one instead of reposting it as a new question. As it stands either one is a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. But no one helps here and the post is being lost on the pages (in my opinion)...

Comment: Yes that's what usually happens when a question involves too much effort. As I said before, your code is too long and too complex to understand, and you're not really forthcoming with explanations. Your best bet is to reduce it too a lot less lines of code and remove all the noise that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @Yoshi Well, I don't know how to explain that better 'cuz I tried to describe everything what I'm trying to achieve now